# Multiple checkbox with button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

How to select topics the user likes before it proceeds using checkboxes. I want the next button to be enabled only after a checkbox is selected.

HTML

```
<a href="search.html"><input type="submit" value="Next" id="next" disabled="disabled"></a>

<ul>
  <li>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkPlant1" unchecked="checked"/>
    <label for="chkPlant1"><img src="img/plant1.jpg" /></label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkPlant2" />
    <label for="chkPlant2"><img src="img/plant2.jpg" /></label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkPlant3" />
    <label for="chkPlant3"><img src="img/plant3.png" /></label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkPlant4" />
    <label for="chkPlant4"><img src="img/plant4.jpg" /></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(function () {
      $("#chkPlant1").change(function () {
        if($('#chkPlant1').is(':checked')) { 
          $("#next").prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
          $("#next").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
  });

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:checked` pseudo-selector with `length` property as it shown below:

```js
$(function() {

  function updateView() {
    // count of all checked inputs with class .checkbox
    if ($("input.checkbox:checked").length > 0) { 
      $("#next").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $("#next").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  }

  // match all inputs with class .checkbox
  $("input.checkbox").change(function(event) {
    updateView();
  });

  // initialize
  updateView();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="search.html"><input type="submit" value="Next" id="next"></a>
<ul>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkPlant1" /></li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkPlant2" /></li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkPlant3" /></li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkPlant4" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Target any input with class `input.checkbox` and not just the first one and check inside if any of them is checked, this will make sure at least one is picked.

```
$("input.checkbox").change(function() {
    if ($("input.checkbox").is(':checked')) {
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("input.checkbox").change(function() {
    if ($("input.checkbox").is(':checked')) {
      $("#next").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $("#next").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="search.html"><input type="submit" value="Next" id="next" disabled="disabled"></a>

<ul>
  <li>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkPlant1" unchecked="checked" />
    <label for="chkPlant1"><img src="img/plant1.jpg" /></label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkPlant2" />
    <label for="chkPlant2"><img src="img/plant2.jpg" /></label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkPlant3" />
    <label for="chkPlant3"><img src="img/plant3.png" /></label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkPlant4" />
    <label for="chkPlant4"><img src="img/plant4.jpg" /></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this could help, if you don't want to use the class

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
  $("#chkPlant1").change(function () {
    if($('#chkPlant1').is(':checked')) { 
      $("#next").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
      $("#next").prop("disabled", true);
    }
   });
  $("#chkPlant2").change(function () {
    if($('#chkPlant2').is(':checked')) { 
      $("#next").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
      $("#next").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
 $...
});

</script>
```